# How to use custom elements without hyphen in their name?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

I have a XML file and want to insert it into HTML. There is `<book>` tags in the XML, so I want to define a custom element `<book>`.

However, it seems that a hypen (`-`) in the name is required...

I don't want to write tags like `<my-book>` in the XML file.

Is there a way?

Comment: Use XSLT or some other method to transform the XML after you load it.

Comment: custom elements _must_ contain a hyphen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Elements **must** contain a hyphen.

But nothing stops you from using `<book>` notation in your XML and then client-side parse all those **unknown tags** to something else. But you will get a FOUC

```html
<my-book-elements>
  <book id="The World according to Garp" />
  <book id="The war of the worlds" />
  <book id="Around the world in eighty days" /> 
  Bye Bye World
</my-book-elements>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-book-elements', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure we can work with the inner DOM nodes
        this.append(...[...this.querySelectorAll("*")].map(node => {
          let book = document.createElement("my-" + node.localName);
          book.id = node.id;
          //node.remove();// not required, innerHTML will replace everything
          return book;
        }));
      });
    }
  });
  customElements.define("my-book", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<div>${this.id}</div>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```